# Plot using different styles based on closing price

Tags: pine-script

I have a simple plot to draw closing price in pinescript v5.

`plot(series=close, title='close', linewidth=2, color=color.lime)`

I would like to modify the plot such that if price of close > 100, the plot will be plotted in dotted line. Otherwise, the plot will be in normal line.

I am using pinescript v5.

I tried the following;

```
plot_style = plot.style_line
if close >= 100
    plot_style := plot.style_cross

plot(close, title='close', linewidth=2, color=color.lime, style=plot_style)
```

I received the error `Error at 652:64 Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'style'='plot_style'. An argument of 'series plot_style' type was used but a 'input plot_style' is expected.`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have dynamic styles in `plot()`. As a workaround, you can have two plots. One for the case `close > 100` and one for `close <= 100`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plot((close > 1) ? close : na, title='close1', linewidth=2, color=color.lime, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot((close <= 1) ? close : na, title='close2', linewidth=2, color=color.lime, style=plot.style_cross)
hline(1, color=color.white)
```

[image]